# shell basename error

Tags: c

I am tryng to get the commands from the base name as well.. Thats the reason why i use something like this after parsing the line...

```
 while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\n') 
                       *line++ = '\0';     

                    line = basename(line);  // base 
                    *argv++ = line;
```

well basename seems working well but if i put a command like ls -l then it gives an error...

inout and output is something like this

```
ls
arg[0]: 'ls' and arg[1]: '(null)'
shellTest

bin/ls
arg[0]: 'ls' and arg[1]: '(null)'
shellTest

ls -l
arg[0]: '-l' and arg[1]: '-l'
Execution of the command is failed
: No such file or directory
```

if i remove `line = basename(line);` then everything is working besides basename so parsing cant be the problem...

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more code.  It looks like you may not be copying where you need to copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the surrounding code that uses `basename()`.  The POSIX standard for [`basename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) says:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `basename()` function shall take the pathname pointed to by path and return a pointer to the final component of the pathname, deleting any trailing `'/'` characters.
>
> If the string pointed to by path consists entirely of the `'/'` character, `basename()` shall return a pointer to the string `"/"`. If the string pointed to by path is exactly `"//"`, it is implementation-defined whether `'/'` or `"//"` is returned.
>
> If path is a null pointer or points to an empty string, `basename()` shall return a pointer to the string `"."`.
>
> The `basename()` function may modify the string pointed to by path, and may return a pointer to static storage that may then be overwritten by a subsequent call to `basename()`.
>
> The `basename()` function need not be thread-safe.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> The `basename()` function shall return a pointer to the final component of path.

There's a lot of wriggle room in that specification.

But it looks a bit as if you are trying to use the same space to store two values at the same time, unsuccessfully.